# How to synchronize two static methods without using the class level lock

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

How do I make getFoo() and getBar() threadsafe? so that at the same time one thread can call getFoo() and another can call getBar()... i.e. I don't want to synchronize on the class level lock..

```
private static Foo foo; 
private static Bar bar;     


private static void initBar() {
    bar = SomeOtherClass.getBarVal();
}

private static void initFoo() {
    foo = SomeOtherClass.getFooVal();
}

public static Foo getFoo() {
    if (foo == null) {
        initFoo();
    }
    return foo;
}

public static Bar getBar() {
    if (bar == null) {
        initBar();
    }
    return bar;
}
```

Comment: You want two threads to access those methods at the same time?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the class-level lock? That's a classic use case.  Make your own lock if you can't use the class.

Comment: Why not making the methods synchronized ?

Comment: I don't want to use the class-level lock cause then while one thread is calling getFoo() another thread won't be able to call getBar()... How can I make my own lock? Do you suggest doing some thing like private static final Object lock = new Object(); and then using lock in the synchronized(lock) block? can you please show with an example...?

Comment: then use two locks for both methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to lock `getFoo()` and `getBar()`, only the init blocks:

```
private static volatile Foo foo; 
private static volatile Bar bar;     
private static final Object fooLock = new Object();
private static final Object barLock = new Object();

private static void initBar() {
    bar = SomeOtherClass.getBarVal();
}

private static void initFoo() {
    foo = SomeOtherClass.getFooVal();
}

public static Foo getFoo() {
    if (foo == null) {
        synchronized (fooLock) {
            if (foo == null) {
                initFoo();
            }
        }
    }
    return foo;
}

public static Foo getBar() {
    if (bar == null) {
        synchronized (barLock) {
            if (bar == null) {
                initBar();
            }
        }
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: See edited answer - you can always replace `MyClass.class` with a plain old `Obejct`, like my edit suggests.

Comment: will only one lock do? or will I have to create two different locks?

Comment: @Manav If you want those methods to be run parallel by two different threads, then you would need two different locks.

Comment: if `initFoo()` and `initBar()` have nothing to do with each other - than yes, two different locks. I'll fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: So I should be using lock1 for getFoo() and lock2 for getBar()??

Comment: So should the null check be inside the synchronized block or outside?

Comment: If both init methods **can** run in parallel without disturbing each other - yes. See my answer above.

Comment: @Manav "So should the null check be inside the synchronized block or outside?" - **both**. Synchronizing is an expensive operation. I first check outside the sync block, since if the object is already initialized, there is no need for synchronizing. Once I've synchronized, I check **again**, to make sure the object hasn't been initialized between the last check and the synchronizing start.

Comment: are there any disadvantages of using our own locks like suggested by you above?

Comment: @Manav disadvantages compared to what other solution? You "waster" memory by creating two extra objects. but gain the performance advantage of not having `initFoo()` and `initBar()` block each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Foo foo;
private static Bar bar;

private static final Object fooLock = new Object();
private static final Object barLock = new Object();

private static void initBar() {
    bar = SomeOtherClass.getBarVal();
}

private static void initFoo() {
    foo = SomeOtherClass.getFooVal();
}

public static Foo getFoo() {
    synchronized(fooLock){
        if (foo == null) {
            initFoo();
        }
    }
    return foo;
}

public static Bar getBar() {
    synchronized(barLock){
        if (bar == null) {
            initBar();
        }
    }
    return bar;
}
```

Use two locks.

**EDIT**

If you are using singleton pattern, I suggest reading on:

[simply singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html)

Comment: checking for null twice once outside and once inside the synchronized blocks will be more efficient..

Comment: hmmm that makes sense... especially the last para on page4.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static Foo getBar() {
      return BarInstanceHolder.barInstance; 
  }

  public static Foo getFoo() {
      return FooInstanceHolder.fooInstance;
  }

  private static final class BarInstanceHolder {
    static final Bar barInstance = SomeOtherClass.getBarVal();   
  }


  private static final class FooInstanceHolder {
    static final Foo fooInstance = SomeOtherClass.getFooVal();   
  }
```

Comment: ok but in my case it might be that at some times the SomeOtherClass.getBarVal() and SomeOtherClass.getFooVal() might return null.. and if they do then next time I want to call them again... in your solution this won't be possible right?... but your solution is good as it is endorsed by effective java...

Comment: your requirement is not clear :( e.g) what is SomeOtherClass..? how it is passed? how it is changed? when it will return null ? if it return  null how calling again will return other than null? I am confused...

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static final class FooInstanceHolder {
static final Foo fooInstance = SomeOtherClass.getFooVal();
```

}

Initialize foo when class FooInstanceHolder is loaded into memory.No method can be called before a class is loaded completely.